# Find and delete specific sentence in first line of emails

Tags: vba, replace, outlook, find

All my emails have this sentence added " this email has come from an external source. Do not click on links or open attachments unless you recognise the sender."

I would like to delete it.; I have made this macro but it does not work. Nothing happens. Other macros do work in outlook session, so it is not a security issue. I would expect the macro to take a minute or so for 100s of emails to search. but nothing happens at all. Can you help ?

```
Sub RemoveExpressionFOLDER()

Dim outNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim outFldr As Outlook.Folder
Dim outMailItems As Outlook.Items
'Dim outMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outMailItem As Object
Dim myinspector As Outlook.Inspector


Set outNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set outFldr = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector


Set outMailItems = outFldr.Items

K = outFldr.Items.Count
```

'MsgBox (K)
    For i = 1 To K

```
If outMailItems(i).Class <> olMail Then GoTo 20
outMailItems(i).Display


    'outMailItems(i).UnRead = True
    outMailItems(i).Body = Replace(outMailItems(i).Body, "THINK SECURE. This 
 email has come from an external source. Do not click on links or open 
 attachments unless you recognise the sender.", "")
'outMailItems(i).HTMLBody = Replace(outMailItems(i).HTMLBody, "THINK SECURE. 
This email has come from an external source. Do not click on links or open 
 attachments unless you recognise the sender.", "")
 outMailItems(i).Save
 Set myinspector = Application.ActiveInspector
 Set outMailItems(i) = myinspector.CurrentItem

 outMailItems(i).Close olSave

 20    Next i
 MsgBox ("cleaned ")

Set outMailItems = Nothing
Set outFldr = Nothing
Set outNS = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: Needs a `outMailItem.Save` to save the changes to the body. If its that weird orange background text line, this may need to be expanded to remove that formatting.

Comment: Body is the text body.  BodyHtml is the Html body.  Outlook only shows the Html body so amending the text body will have no effect.  Try amending BodyHtml.

Comment: I have taken on board 2 comments from the community Mike and Tony; thanks: I added a "save"line and amended to "HTMLbody" in the loop. but still no change; also i added a temporary counter too see how many iterations were made in the loop, but instead of going through all emails ( 100+) it stops at 3 or 4 depending on the folder ( drafts or inbox). this is strange ?

Comment: Tested functionality with HTMLBody works fine for me.  You've either got some formatting incorrect in your replace statement or you are filtering emails you don't want to update. You're currently in the drafts. Are those the emails you want to update?  Note - that even if you remove the TEXT it will not remove the HTML formatting. It may be better to identify the element tag and remove it entirely with the replace if possible.

Comment: Solve most of the issues with your help.I have the impression that fiind/replace does not work with EXISTING emails in Inbox. They need to be opened (displayed) which is  not practical at all ?

Comment: Hi Christian if you use @(username) we'll see your comments. Otherwise we won't be notified.  Whats the end result of this? To cleanup emails in your inbox? To adjust them before forwarding them?  If its the first - its looking like display then save/close is the only option that I can find. If you want to edit before sending you can use the the forwarding mechanisms in vba that will allow you to edit the body of the draft before sending without the need for display/save/close. @Tony Dallimore may have more info.

Comment: Christian Fischer: Mike, I used outMailItems(i).Display to display last 10 emails of the selected folder , then find/replace, finally outMailItems(i).Save; see above code. but the 1st email remains now open (displayed). Is there a way to close a displayed email before moving to the next one ? or at the end of the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to open the mailitems.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveExpressionFOLDER()

Dim outFldr As folder
Dim outItems As Items
Dim outMailItem As MailItem

Dim i As Long
Dim cleanCount As Long

Set outFldr = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Set outItems = outFldr.Items

For i = 1 To outItems.Count

    If outItems(i).Class = olMail Then

        Set outMailItem = outItems(i)

        With outMailItem

            'Debug.Print .Subject

            If InStr(.Body, "THINK SECURE. This email has come from an external source. Do not click on links or open attachments unless you recognise the sender.") Then

                If .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
                    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "THINK SECURE. This email has come from an external source. Do not click on links or open attachments unless you recognise the sender.", "")
                Else
                    .Body = Replace(.Body, "THINK SECURE. This email has come from an external source. Do not click on links or open attachments unless you recognise the sender.", "")
                End If

                .SAVE

                cleanCount = cleanCount + 1

            End If

        End With

    End If

Next i

MsgBox (cleanCount & " mailitems cleaned.")

End Sub
```